# How to use an unix user with RabbitMQ (Celery/Django)?

Tags: django, unix, rabbitmq, celery

I want to use celery and RabbitMQ with an existing unix user on my server.

How to use an unix user with RabbitMQ ?

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost myvhost
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost myUnixUser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

And use it with celery

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://myUnixUser@localhost:5672/myvhost/'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can't be done because you can't connect to RabbitMQ using Unix Socket.

Only connecting with "unix socket" allows you to use "unix user" for authentication.